# How can I use js var in html?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm actually trying to use a js var in my html code like this :

---

In javascript code :

```
var test = 'This is a test';
```

And in the html :

```
<p>display var test here</p>
```

How can I display the value of my js var in html like this ?

Comment: there's plenty ways of doing that - what effort have you made?

Comment: What have you tried so far, show us that code and we may be able to help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<p id="paragraph"></p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var test = 'This is a test';
document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = test;
```